# Deploying a Flask app to shared hosting at godaddy

Tags: python, cgi

I got shared economy hosting at godaddy, and I finally got cgi working with python. I created a simple cgi script:

```
#!/../bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<body bgcolor='000'>"
print "<font face='Courier New' color='white'>Test python page. CGI extension </font>"
print "</body>"
```

and that works just fine as you can see here: http://jottingdown.com/pytest.cgi 
Now I would like to deploy my hello world flask app so I follow the guide on the flask website http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/ and other guides on how to deploy a website using cgi but I keep getting error 500 http://jottingdown.com/flask/test.cgi.

My test.cgi script:

```
#!/../bin/python   
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from Flask_HelloWorld import app
CGIHandler().run(app)
```

My Flask_HelloWorld script:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Do anybody know what I'm doing wrong, or got any experience with deploying to godaddy?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I see this question doesn't have an accepted answer.
The directory structure, content in the .htaccess file also matters when depliying in shared hosting.

Below link has a detailed description on deploying flask app in Apache shared hosting

https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e

Hope it helps.

Comment: -1 -- a good answer on SO includes description of what to do, rather than just pointing at the link, since links often die, like it is the case now.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă:Thanks for pointing out. I have moved the documentation to Medium .You can check [here](https://medium.com/@mohdejazsiddiqui/deploy-flask-app-in-apache-shared-hosting-5b3c82c8fd5e)

Answer (score 0):

Add `.htaccess` to the web directory

```
#.htaccess
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /cgi-bin/test.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Assuming you have the shared hosting directory like:

```
shared_root_directory/
---- CGI-bin/
     ---- test.cgi
     ---- Flask_HelloWorld.py
---- web/
     ---- .htaccess
```

Both "Flask_HelloWorld.py" and "test.cgi" must be/have "755" file permission.

Answer (score -1):

The docs that vokuheila cites are the ones to read, but they are not quite complete. I too struggled with 500 errors. See my post to [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259435/deploy-flask-application-on-11-shared-hosting-with-cgi).

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more explicit. The question is about 500 status errors. The fatal aspect of those errors tends to make figuring out the cause difficult if all that you do is look at symptoms, because the only symptom that you typically get, particularly on shared hosting, is the bare 500 error. At the post that I cite, which is by me, I discuss, for the benefit of others like me who are hardly beyond the noob stage, three ways of getting error info printouts in the cgi/python/Flask context. That is why I offered my answer.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to take a took at this:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/

Comment: http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/02/14/serving-a-python-flask-website-on-hostmonster/

Comment: consider adding which part of that page is relevant to OP's question, since they specify they have already visited that page